# battery chargers - AGM and lithium

Tags: battery-charging, lead-acid, lithium

I am working on an inverter with a battery charger for a 24V,200AH AGM battery pack. The battery charger current can be adjusted from 10 to 50 amps. Now, I want to be able to also a charge a lithium battery (24V,150AH) with this charger. Since the lithium iron phosphate  battery has a BMS along with it which will prevent over charging and over discharging and also controls temperature, I can use a normal charger, right ? without a cell balancing module in the charger as the BMS takes care of it ? I need to only be able to adjust the discharge cut off voltage and charging cut off voltage for the entire 24V battery pack as per the manufacturer's data sheet. The lithium battery I am talking about there is one which has BMS integrated inside the battery pack.

Answer (score 1):

It should be safe to use the same charger for both battery types.

AGM batteries are usually charged to a peak voltage of 2.4V per cell, which is 28.8V for a 12 cell 24V battery. LiFePO4 cells are fully charged at 3.6V per cell, which for an 8 cell '24V' battery is also 28.8V.

[How to charge Lithium Iron Phosphate](http://How%20to%20charge%20Lithium%20Iron%20Phosphate)

> A LiFePO4 battery can be safely overcharged to 4.2 volts per cell, but
>   higher voltages will start to break down the organic electrolytes.
>   Nevertheless, it is common to charge a 12 volt a 4-cell series pack
>   with a lead acid battery charger. The maximum voltage of these
>   chargers, whether AC powered, or using a car's alternator, is 14.4
>   volts. This works fine, but lead acid chargers will lower their
>   voltage to 13.8 volts for the float charge, and so will usually
>   terminate before the LiFe pack is at 100%.